# View list drop down

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

> In my eclipse application when more than 3 views are open, I need a drop down as shown in picture clicking on which gives me the list of rest of the views.

[image]

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I need the same functionality of drop down in my application when number of views goes more than 3..